# CLASSPATH issue while accessing Mysql on Linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, classpath

I have Mysql installed on my Linux box and wrote a sample program to access one of it's table.
I am using 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar'

The code is working fine if i put the jar in 'jre/lib/ext'. However, other ways of recognizing that jar are not working. I tried with setting $CLASSPATH and tried to use '.' current directory.

It's failing with the following error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

Comment: `However, other ways of recognizing that jar are not working. I tried with setting $CLASSPATH and tried to use '.' current directory.` please elaborate this

Comment: one way is to set CLASSPATH right? I just came to know that when i set CLASSPATH in linux, I have to put the path for .class files as well in that CLASSPATH. Which is not the case in Windows. Windows recognizes the .class file in the current directory along with the CLASSPATH.  the second way is to use the current directory without setting the CLASSPATH. However, as per the below answer it's not working either. I have to explicitly mention them using -cp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually don't use the global `$CLASSPATH` variable, the easiest way to get it running is

```
java -cp .;/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar[;<other libs>] pkg.name.MyApplication
```

**Sidenote**

If you have your application exportet to a jar with a `Main-Class` attribute ("executable jar") and start it with `java -jar myjar.jar`, then you **have to** add all required libraries to the jars manifest, `$CLASSPATH` and `-cp` are ignored in this case. And that's why I usually don't use the `-jar` option...

**Edit**

To answer your additional question: If the current directory was added to the classpath by default, then the location from where the application was started could influence the application itself.

Imagine an application inside a jar and a start command

```
 java -cp application.jar com.example.Main
```

Now we have a defined environment: only the content of application.jar (and the jre classes) are on the classpath and part of the application. If the current directory was added to the classpath automatically then all files at the current location (and at locations of all subfolders) would be on the classpath too, intend or not. With a result, that the application might work if started from the users home directory but maybe not if started from the root directory (`/`).

Comment: cool. Got it! Got some questions too....  why should we explicitly set  to look into current directory (both .class file & jar).

Comment: why it can't recognize current directory as default location as per the document.

Comment: Alright. I wrote a hello world program in a particular directory, then compiled and executed well. I have nothing in $CLASSPATH. So, the thing 'The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.'  from the document is true......    then my question would be Why it's only looking for .class files in the current directory why not jars ?          am I missing any point ?